# multiple tables in excel worksheet and sql file needed as output

Tags: sql, excel

I have a single excel worksheet which contains lots of table definitions around 50. Table definitions are like:

```
Table School
Name Varchar2 20
Marks Number 5
```

These values are in different columns in excel and there lot of similar tables. 
Now I need to generate a sql script using the excel file. The output script should consists of create table statemnts for all the tables. I just need sql script for all the tables.
Let me know how can I do it.

Comment: can you give some more details and it should be automatic..

Comment: Visit this link http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ABXa6X18nyo  use macro to get your expected result

Comment: thanks Prince, will look into it. Any other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use macro youtube.com/watch?v=ABXa6X18nyo.

Another way just concatenate the strings, for exanple
[image]

```
="create table "&B1&"("&A2&" "&B2&","&A3&" "&B3&");"
```

Type this in any other column you will get the result as `create table School(Name  Varchar2 20,Marks  Number 5);

For this visit http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-join-text-strings-in-excel-2010-with-the-op.html
`

Comment: once i get all the create statements then how to generate the final .sql file

Comment: Once you create all the statements.Select and Copy all the rows of the required column For eg: In above image its "C" - Column where you applied the formula. Then open a notepad and paste it. Then save it as *.sql file. Thats it. Just now I tired the same. Its working for me

Comment: but this is going to be a manual process, can't we have something which can be done automatically because my database is huge.

Comment: You may have large database, But it will take just 2 to 5 mins to create a .sql file. Just select the columns and paste this ="create table "&B1&"("&A2&" "&B2&","&A3&" "&B3&");" then copy the generated statement and paste it in notepad. It is just 2 to 5 mins work

Comment: yeah I understand and thanks, but my requirement is that it should be done automatically.

Comment: Oh ok. If you need this to be done automatically, then you have to write code in Java, C# or any language to read a Excel file (In the code itself you have to append "create table.....etc, then open and write it a .sql file